# Get List of Projects in each Domain in ALM using OTA API

Tags: api, rest, hp-quality-center

From Google the below command can be used to get the list of available domains in ALM:
**QCConnection.VisibleDomains**

But I am not able to find the code to get the list of projects under each domain.
Please let me know how to get the projects list under each and every domain or a particular domain.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... The below code works just fine...

```
For i = 1 To QCConnection.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors.Count
  If QCConnection.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors.Item(i).DomainName = "Your Domain" Then
     Debug.Print QCConnection.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors.Item(i).Name
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
For i = 1 To QCCon.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors.Count <br>
For Each projectName In QCCon.ProjectsListEx(QCCon.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors.Item(i).DomainName) <br>
        Debug.Print QCCon.GetAllVisibleProjectDescriptors.Item(i).DomainName & "/" & projectName <br>
Next projectName <br>
Next i<br>
```

Let us know if it works for you.